# pyads.pyads.ADSError: ADSError: Service is not supported by server (1793)

Tags: python, twincat

pyads.pyads.ADSError: ADSError: Service is not supported by server (1793)

```
import pyads

pyads.open_port()
print(pyads.get_local_address())

plc= pyads.Connection('169.254.188.210.1.1',32915)
print("connecting...")
plc.open()
print("connected!")
res=plc.read_by_name('MAIN.Lichtschalter_Hobby1' , pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL )
```

connecting...

connected!

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\shift\twincat.py", line 10, in  res=plc.read_by_name('MAIN.Lichtschalter_Hobby1' , pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL )

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyads\ads.py", line 519, in read_by_name return adsSyncReadByName(self._adr, data_name, plc_datatype)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyads\pyads.py", line 60, in wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyads\pyads.py", line 374, in adsSyncReadByName dataName, PLCTYPE_STRING

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyads\pyads.py", line 60, in wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyads\pyads.py", line 299, in adsSyncReadWriteReq raise ADSError(err_code)

pyads.pyads.ADSError: ADSError: Service is not supported by server (1793)

[Finished in 0.3s]

Anyone Have the solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to Twincat 2 change your port from (32915?) to 801, 
otherwise if you want to connect to Twincat 3 change your port to 851.